# Can one embed two division rings in a common one?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, division-ring

> Given two division rings $R_1,R_2$ having the same characteristic, is there a simple way to find a division ring $R$ with two embedings $R_1\subset R$ and $R_2\subset R$ ?

Comment: @rschwieb: no, it's not true. Take any division quaternion algebra $Q$ over a field $K$. Then $Q\otimes_K Q$ is the full matrix ring.

Comment: @GreginGre ok... Thanks for letting me know. I knew I might not be remembering correctly :)